# цветовая карта поверх изображения

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Прошу подсказать, а лучше показать  как цветовую карту лучше наложить на изображение?

Например у меня есть изображение 400 на 400 test.png, я его отображаю через plt, а потом на pcolor рисую цветовую карту с
alpha = 0.25, но он делает не так как я хочу... Картинку не четко видно, вместе с colorbar (как будто это не совсем альфа-канал, а какое-то смешение), плюс сетка какая-то =(

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
image = plt.imread('test.png')
plt.imshow(image)
vals = []
for i in range(0,200):
    if i <50:
        val_list = [2]*200
    elif i <100:
        val_list = [5]*200
    elif i <150:
        val_list = [10]*200
    vals.append(val_list)
plt.pcolor(vals, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet', 11), alpha = 0.25)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: Исходник]

[image: Результат]

Пробовал изменить размер картинки 200 на 200. Не получилось =(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конечно можно не заморачиваться ) Сделать две картинки одну с подложкой .png, другую с pcolor (без альфа) и потом наложить одно на другое. Велосипедить не хочется)))

Comment: а вы не пробовали изображение сделать 200х200 ?

Comment: S. Nick, а смысл? Задняя часть и хвост слона все равно так же будут выглядеть)

Comment: а вы попробуйте.

Comment: Нет( Не получилось... Результат примерно такой же =(   картинку прикрепил. Сетка только меньше.

Comment: вместо pcolor нужно использовать pcolormesh (сетка как раз появлялась из-за того что pcolor обрисовывает края точки, там тоже можно что-то настроить, но я пока к этому не пришел). Да и вообще по документации рекомендуют использовать pcolormesh, вроде как она быстрее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image = plt.imread('test200.png')
plt.imshow(image)
vals = []

for i in range(0, 200,1):
    if i < 50:
        val_list = [2] * 200
    elif i < 100:
        val_list = [5] * 200
    elif i < 150:
        val_list = [10] * 200
    vals.append(val_list)

plt.pcolormesh (vals, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet', 11), alpha=0.5)
plt.axis('off')
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image: Результат]

Спасибо, @S.Nick, натолкнули на мысль сделать картинку **`200x200`**)